# Define custom function in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

How I can define custom function and then use it in test function, it works when I run single test case but don't work when I run multiple test cases.

```
class AlphaTest(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
            self.driver.get("http://google.com/")

         def asserTrueId(self, value):
             self.assertTrue(self.driver.find_element_by_id(value))
             time.sleep(1)


         def test_flush_cache(self):
            self.asserTrueId("block-menu-menu-menu-for-directories")
```

Comment: What happens when you run multiple test cases?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `unittest.setUpClass()` to instantiate a class level `driver` instance. Similarly you can use `tearDownClass()` to clean up class level variables if required.

Since `setUpClass()` and `tearDownClass()` will only be run once inside your Test class you can use this to guarantee there is only one driver.  Otherwise using `setUp()` would be run for each test method - each creating a browser instance each time - which could be slow and possibly memory inefficient.

```
class AlphaTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        cls.driver.get("http://google.com/")

    def asserTrueId(self, value):
        self.assertTrue(self.driver.find_element_by_id(value))
        time.sleep(1)

    def test_flush_cache(self):
        self.asserTrueId("block-menu-menu-menu-for-directories")
```